# Is my Nikkor lens malfunctioning?

Tags: lens, nikon, troubleshooting

I have an AF-S Nikkor 18-135 mm lens.  While I initially suspected an issue with the camera, I found that my two Nikon camera bodies work perfectly well with other lens, and this lens works with no other Nikon body.  When I say "work", I mean that the pictures I take are all over-exposed when on automatic.  In normal light, the flash always pops up, and when I take a normal picture in normal daylight, the pictures are all washed out through over-exposure.  I took one camera body (a D80) into a repair facility and they said that all the sensors, etc. were perfectly fine.

So I am wondering if this could be a lens problem, which it seems to be, and what is going wrong and whether it is fixable.  Has anyone encountered this problem, or have thoughts on the likely causes of the problem?

Comment: The same lens doesn't work on any camera? The cameras all work with other lenses? Why do you possibly think it might not be the lens?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's the lens, it sounds like the Iris (aperture) isn't closing down properly.

Take the lens to the repair shop you took the D80 to and get it serviced, it will not be something you can do yourself without a clean-room.

Comment: A quick test for proper function of the aperture blades is to try taking photos in Av at max and min aperture and see if only the photos that are stopped-down are overexposed.

Comment: You do the test in M mode really (or A as there is no such thing as Av mode on a Nikon.)  Since the body is known to be working it has to be a problem with the lens either way so it still needs professional attention (or replacement).